# Python program to iterate and print using re

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small program/class where I find a certain block of text in a file.  I then pull certain information from that block and simplify it and print/return it.

This:

```
it /'properties'/'someJenkinsInformation'/'strategy(class:hudson.LogRotator)'
{
'daysToKeep'('90')
'numToKeep'('300')
'artifactDaysToKeep'('3')
'artifactNumToKeep'('3')
}
```

To this:

```
logRotator(90, 300, 3, 3)
```

What I have so far:

```
# Search test.txt for 'LogRotator'
def find_text(self):
    super.find_text()
    self.convert_to_string()
    # now that we have found our line, find the next piece


# From find_text print 'logRotator(90, 300, 3, 3)'
def create_text():
    j = 0

    while self.file_text[line_num + j].strip() != "}":
        while self.file_text[line_num + j].strip() != ")":
            match = re.search(r"[0-9]+", self.file_text[line_num + j])
    # this is mostly where I get lost in 
    # how to iterate through the above block and how to pull out what I 
    # need in order to print
```

Comment: What is the superclass? Shouldn't `find_text()` take an argument telling it what to search for?

Comment: What is `line_num`?

Comment: Append the numbers from each line to a list. When the loop ends you can use `.join` to turn the list into the string `"90, 300, 3, 3"`

Comment: @Barmar Yes there is a superclass, also using a decorator pattern; so to clarify the find_text() is working properly as it stops at the correct place in test.txt where LogRotator is found.  Where I'm stuck is in the create_text method.  Note: I missed adding the paramters (self, line_num) for create_text

Comment: So you add the number that `re.search` matches to a list, then join it into the argument list string. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I'm new so there isn't a problem per se.

Comment: Okay will do thank-you for the tip!  Part of being new is learning etiquette as well.  Part of being in the top .01% for folks like you should be in recognizing that and assisting those like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not altogether clear about what you're asking. This might be the technique you need.

It involves line-by-line parsing, switching on processing when a '{' is encountered and quitting when the matching '}' is seen.

```
import re

processing = False
result = 'logRotator('
with open('temp.txt') as text:
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('{'):
            processing = True
        elif line.startswith('}'):
            break
        else:
            if processing:
                m = re.search('\d+', line)
                if m:
                    result += '%s, '%m.group()
print (result[:-2]+')')
```

Here's the output.

```
logRotator(90, 300, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Thank-you!  I'm almost there and this was a huge help.